C# Form to OfficeOpenXMml file I/O writing error
I am trying to create and write to a xlsx file from a c# form.
private async void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //variables are pulled from the form on save button click
   PullRecord record = new PullRecord
   WellName = wellNametextBox.Text,
   dateFinished = dateFinishedTimePicker.Value.ToShortDateString()
   };
{ 
{


using (FileStream fs = File.Open("C:\\Users\\4ndrocles\\Desktop\\Pulling Reports\\output.xlsx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))  
// opening file to read with file location 

    try
    {
        ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = OfficeOpenXml.LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
         
         using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo("C:\\Users\\4ndrocles\\Desktop\\Pulling Reports\\output.xlsx")))
        {
            // add a new worksheet to the empty workbook with the name created from wellname and date finished
            ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add($"{record.WellName} - {record.dateFinished}");
            
            //Add the headers
            worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Well Name";
            worksheet.Cells[1, 3].Value = record.WellName;
            worksheet.Cells[6, 1].Value = "Date Finished";
            worksheet.Cells[6, 3].Value = record.dateFinished;
            package.Save();
                            MessageBox.Show("File Saved");
                        }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                        MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException)
            {                                       
                MessageBox.Show("File does not exist.");
            }

Errors:
When the output.xlsx file exists I get this error even though no file is open verified through process monitor
IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\4ndrocles\Desktop\Pulling Reports\output.xlsx' because it is being used by another process.

When there is no output.xlsx file in the folder I get the error
'Could not find file 'C:\Users\4ndrocles\Desktop\Pulling Reports\output.xlsx'


You open a filestream fs but then use the constructor of ExcelPackage that takes a FileInfo and will therefor also open the file. That causes the exception

IOException: The process cannot access the file 'file' because it is being used by another process.

The "another process" is in this cases your own program but the exception doesn't make a distinction between these cases.
Note that if you have that specific xlsx file open in Excel, you'll get the same exception.
To fix the issue use the correct constructor:
 using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(fs))

If there is no file yet you need to Create the file, not Open it. FileMode offers a value for that OpenOrCreate
var file = @"C:\Users\4ndrocles\Desktop\Pulling Reports\output.xlsx";
using (var fs = File.Open(file, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))  


